# Errors with the following algorithm -inputenc Error

Tags: algorithms

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\begin{document

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{PUML Algorithm}
\label{PUML Algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{Path\textendash Binary table for Path}{}
    \For {i = 1 to Number of Nodes}
    \For {j = 1 to Number of Nodes}
    \State $fx$ = $\left\{ \begin{array}{rl}$
      $ 1     &  \text{N(i) }  \\ 0$ $& \text{otherwise}$
      $\end{array} \right$
    \If $N (i) connect to N (j)$
        \State Matrix element represent as 1
    \Else
        \State Matrix element represent as 0
    \EndIf
    \EndFor
    \EndFor
    \State $D =\sum f(x)$
    \State $L=max (d)$
    \State  Calculate the node connection for Lth node and place          

    \State Update the binary table by eliminating the node from binary table
    \State Initialize particles
    \State Position of particles = x and y coordinating points of node location.
        \State $Velocity = random (number of nodes)$
        \State Check fitness for given position by using objective function.
        \State $F_{Position}$ = $\sum {i=1}^n$ ${i\times\cos⁡((i+1)\times particle+i)}\times \sum{j=1}^m$ ${j\times\cos⁡((j+1)\times particle+j) + Weight(Particle)}$

        \State $ Minimum (F_Position)$ 
        \State $Velocity= w \times velocity+c1 \times(r1*(L_Position-Position))+c2 \times(r2  \times (G_Position-Position))$
        \State $Position = Position + Velocity$

            \For {k = 1 to iteration}
            \If $Present_fitness < Last_fitness$
            \State Update fitness value
\EndIf
\State $Update velocity and position$
\EndFor
           \State $ Find maximum (fitness value), mf = max (fitness)$
           \State $Place SELECTED INDEX on that node. Pth_((x,y) )=N(Ind(mf))$
           \State $ Update binary table by eliminating the node from binary table$
           \State $Loop to Step 6 until binary table gets empty$

\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Can some one help me i am getting errors in the following portions

```
  \State $fx$ = $\left\{ \begin{array}{rl}$
      $ 1     &  \text{N(i) }  \\ 0$ $& \text{otherwise}$
      $\end{array} \right$
    \If $N (i) connect to N (j)$
```

And`

```
  \State $F_{Position}$ = $\sum {i=1}^n$ ${i\times\cos⁡((i+1)\times particle+i)}\times \sum{j=1}^m$ ${j\times\cos⁡((j+1)\times particle+j) + Weight(Particle)}$

        \State $ Minimum (F_Position)$ 
        \State $Velocity= w \times velocity+c1 \times(r1*(L_Position-Position))+c2 \times(r2  \times (G_Position-Position))$
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need so many `$` especially for `array`. Also it is better to use `\text` (or `\mathrm`) at many places. Further `max` → `\max` etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode,amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{PUML Algorithm}
\label{PUML Algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{Path\textendash Binary table for Path}{}
    \For {i = 1 to Number of Nodes}
    \For {j = 1 to Number of Nodes}
    \State $f_x = \left\{ \begin{array}{rl}
       1     &  \text{N(i) }  \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}
      \end{array} \right.$
    \If $N (i)$ connect to $N (j)$
        \State Matrix element represent as 1
    \Else
        \State Matrix element represent as 0
    \EndIf
    \EndFor
    \EndFor
    \State $D =\sum f(x)$
    \State $L=\max (d)$
    \State  Calculate the node connection for $L^{\text{th}}$ node and place

    \State Update the binary table by eliminating the node from binary table
    \State Initialize particles
    \State Position of particles $= x$ and $y$ coordinating points of node location.
        \State $\text{Velocity} = \text{random (number of nodes)}$
        \State Check fitness for given position by using objective function.
        \State $F_{\text{Position}}$ = $\sum {i=1}^n$ ${i\times\cos⁡((i+1)\times \text{particle}+i)}\times \sum{j=1}^m$ ${j\times\cos⁡((j+1)\times \text{particle}+j) + \text{Weight(Particle)}}$

        \State  Minimum $(F_\text{Position})$
        \State $\text{Velocity}= w \times \text{velocity}+c1 \times(r1*(L_\text{Position$-$Position}))+c2 \times(r2  \times (G_\text{Position$-$Position}))$
        \State $\text{Position} = \text{Position} + \text{Velocity}$

            \For {k = 1 to iteration}
            \If $ \,\text{Present}_\text{fitness} < \text{Last}_\text{fitness}$
            \State Update fitness value
\EndIf
\State Update velocity and position
\EndFor
           \State  Find maximum (fitness value), $mf = \max (\text{fitness})$
           \State Place SELECTED INDEX on that node. $P^{\text{th}}_((x,y) )=N(Ind(mf))$
           \State  Update binary table by eliminating the node from binary table
           \State Loop to Step 6 until binary table gets empty

\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure about many `text` I have used as I don't know what kind of parameters they are. Also `Ind(mf)` is left as such which needs attention.

Comment: `cases` environment instead of the handmade version on line 4. I would recommend `$L$-th` and not the exponent, which may confuse the reader, whereas the hyphen cannot be mistaken for a minus sign. Possibly the two overlong formulas should be broken across lines by hand and surely not realized as three or four distinct formulas (whenever I see `$x$ = $y$`, I feel that something is wrong). I'm afraid that other `$` are amiss in your version.

Comment: @egreg Agreed. I was so confused with those many `$`'s that I could not take all of them. With your comment, I hope OP will do the rest. :) Thanks.

Comment: @HarishKumar-\State $F_{\text{Position}}$ = $\sum {i=1}^n$ ${i\times\cos⁡((i+1)\times \text{particle}+i)}\times \sum{j=1}^m$ ${j\times\cos⁡((j+1)\times \text{particle}+j) + \text{Weight(Particle)}}$ - this bit is still giving me an error